# Returning mutable reference of trait in vector

Tags: rust, mutable, dereference

New to rust, I'm trying to build a state stack.

```
pub trait State {
    fn tick(&mut self);
}

pub struct StateStack {
    stack: Vec<Box<dyn State>>,
}

impl StateStack {
    pub fn push(&mut self, state: Box<dyn State>) {
        self.stack.push(state);
    }

    pub fn current(&mut self) -> &mut dyn State
    {
        &**self.stack.last_mut().expect("No state in stack")
    }
}
```

When compiling, I get this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
14 |     pub fn current(&mut self) -> &mut dyn State
   |                                  -------------- expected `&mut dyn State` because of return type
15 |     {
16 |         &**self.stack.last_mut().expect("No state in stack")
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ types differ in mutability
   |
   = note: expected mutable reference `&mut dyn State`
                      found reference `&(dyn State + 'static)`
```

I don't understand where this `State + 'static'` come from, is this even the issue ?
I'm not sure where to begin to analyze this error. I think I get the *deref chain* right, but I feel I might be missing something here.

As a side question, I'm an OOP developper, and I'm not sure that what I'm doing is going the rustly way. Any other architecture to considere for state stack ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you downgrade the mutable reference you got with `last_mut` to an immutable reference when you use `&**`. You need to instead take a mutable reference and that will solve the issue:

```rust
 &mut **self.stack.last_mut().expect("No state in stack")
```

As for `&(dyn State + 'static')`, you can mostly just ignore the `'static`. Anonymous traits (`dyn Trait`) are not concrete types so they may not all share the same lifetime requirements. `dyn State + 'static` indicates an anonymous `State` trait which can survive for a lifetime of `'static`. `'static` just means that a lifetime in unconstrained and could be placed in a static context. Most types have a lifetime of `'static` so it does not get included in regular use. Some types with `'static` lifetimes would be primitives like `u32` or `f64`. Any `dyn Trait` which does not include a lifetime gets an implicit `'static`.

Comment: Thanks. I was focused on `&` being a deref operator, and not a deref to immutable. Since the content of the `SceneStack` should only be available during the lifetime of a `SceneStack` instance, should I add an explicit lifetime on it ?